# convert a python string to a comma delimited, double quoted list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a python string to a comma delimited list object.

Example : `s = "one, two, three"`

What I want is `s = ["one", "two", "three"]`

Thanks,

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: does `s = s.split(", ")` work for what you need?

Comment: Do you want each item in the list to be a string, including the double quotes, or are you not sure that single quotes and double quotes are the same in python?

Comment: Each item in the list to be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: @Sappaa ... but, in Python `""` strings and `''` are essentially equivalent. They both represent the same string objects

Comment: Thanks for the help M Z. split works fine.

Comment: @Sappaa there are *no commas or quotes in the list*. That is very important to understand. Lists don't have "delimiters"

Answer (score 4):

Easy answer, `print(s.split(", "))` can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `s.split(", ")` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple split by comma s.split(",")